# can we change the speed of animation on zooming in/out in highmaps

Tags: highcharts, highmaps

I am trying to change the animation speed of zoom in/out in highmaps. I can do it for loading the map and for series loading but I want it when user click on some country and country get zoomed in with slow animation. Is there any trick or config. property to do so?

```
 series: [{
    animation:{
      duration: 1000  
    },
    type: 'pie',
    name: 'Percentuale per periodo',
    data: [
        ['2 anni',   13.0],
        ['3 anni',      41],
        ['4 anni',    17],
        ['5 anni',     17],
        ['7 anni',   4],
        ['8 anni',   8]
    ]
}]
```

Comment: It looks like a bug. I reported it [here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6315) The bug appeared in Highmaps 5.0.4 - if you are ok with using the previous version, you can set chart.animation.duration to a higher value - http://jsfiddle.net/toptb28q/

Comment: Thank you so much.